# How to replace just one newline between > and < in unix

Tags: linux, unix, sed, newline

Lets say i have a text:

```
"this\n is >\n<"
```

and i want to replace the newline with none which will result in:

```
"this\n is ><"
```

How to achieve this ?

i tried using the following:

```
echo "this\n is >\n<" | sed -e 's/>\n<//g'
```

But it didn't work out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In fact, echo a string without -e just treated the string as plain text. So, the sed you using only delete string "\n".

Comment: Are those `\n`s literally the 2 characters backslash and n or are they representing literal newline characters?

Comment: it is a newline[as mentioned in the header]. My objective is to remove just one newline between > and <. Like >\n< as mentioned in the example above.

Comment: Any genius ideas please..........?

Answer (score 3):

Escape `\` with `\`:

```
echo "this\n is >\n<" | sed -e 's/>\\n</></g'
```

Output:

```
this\n is ><
```

Comment: This doesn't work. i tried it. After echo, the \n becomes newline and sed is unable to identify it anyways. Thanks for the response anyways. My objective is to remove just one newline between > and <. Like >\n< as mentioned in the example above.