# How to remove only one newline between > [greater than] and < [less than] in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, newline

Lets consider that there is a text in the following format:

```
"this\n is >\n<"
```

and i want to truncate the newline only between > and < which will result in:

```
"this\n is ><"
```

How to achieve this ?

I tried using the following:

```
echo "this\n is >\n<" | sed -e 's/>\n<//g'
```

and

```
echo "this\n is >\n<" | sed -e 's/>\\n</></g'
```

But none of them work out. Any suggestions from genius minds ?

Comment: The string in `echo "this\n is >\n<"` does not contain any newline characters.  It contains a slash followed by a letter n.  Did you intend to have newlines or did you want `\` `n`?

Comment: exact same question was asked few days back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422453/how-to-replace-just-one-newline-between-and-in-unix

Comment: This might be a duplicate question but have you managed to provide any solution ?..........It is easy to mark duplicates but hard to find solutions mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/>\n</></;ta;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and if the newline is between `>` and `<` remove it. Then print and delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: Thanx potong.You are truly a genius !

Answer (score 1):

sed works on a line-by-line basis, but you can sort of hack it into shape:

```
printf 'this\n is >\n<\n' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/>\n</></g'
```

This is an older-known pattern you can find in some other places.

Essentially, `:a` creates a label, `N` combines the current and next line in the pattern space, `$!ba` branches to a if not at the end (meaning that it keeps going until all the input is in one pattern-space), and then the next is the substitution (`s/>\n</></g`), which now works on all the lines.

There are other options, but this is probably the most portable, as sed will be more places than other tools that can do it like Perl.  You could probably hack it in with awk, but I don't know off the top of my head how to do that without it being far more verbose than this sed solution.

Comment: Oh, and I've used printf here instead of echo only because echo doesn't handle escapes portably, and it's unpredictable what your local echo might decide to do with them.

Comment: Thanx for the response Taywee. We already got a winner here "Potong" :D

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the string with `\` `n`

You were very close:

```
$ echo "this\n is >\n<" | sed -e 's/>\\n</></g'
this\n is ><
```

In sed, `\n` is a newline character.  Your string, however, does not have newline characters: it has slashes followed by `n`.  So, we need to tell sed to look for slash-n.  This is done by doubling the slash.

#### Using the string with newline characters

With `echo` (no options), the string has no newline characters:

```
$ echo "this\n is >\n<"
this\n is >\n<
```

If we use printf, however, the `\` `n` sequences are converted to newlines:

```
$ printf "this\n is >\n<"
this
 is >
<
```

We can remove the newline between the angle brackets using GNU sed:

```
$ printf "this\n is >\n<" | sed -z 's/>\n</></g'
this
 is ><
```

(On Mac OSX, GNU sed is called `gsed`.)

Comment: " Your string, however, does not have newline characters: it has slashes followed by n"  Really depends on your echo implementation.  zsh echo interprets escapes by default.  We can assume that OP isn't actually echoing in their real use case, or is echoing a built string without literal slashes.  Your example also does not work with GNU sed before version 4.2.2 because of the `-z` flag, which makes it unportable.

Comment: @Taywee (1) The question is not tagged `zsh`; it is tagged `shell` which, as per the tag text, implies POSIX compatibility.  POSIX `echo` does not interpret `\n`.  (2) GNU sed 4.2.2 was released in 2012.  In 2016, that makes it old news.  (3) _"We can assume that OP isn't actually..."_:  Until the OP clarifies, such assumptions are merely guesses.  (4)  If it matters, your solution is also GNU-specific and therefore not portable.   Overall, though, your answer is a good answer.  My answer was focused on a slightly different possible issue.

Comment: Thanx John for your amazing answer. Unfortunately, as Taywee suspected, '-z' option isn't available in my GNU sed. But this is one of the brilliant answers found so far but not applicable to my scenario with the version of GNU sed I have. I exactly want to do this [What you said]: 
 this
 is ><